# Rails validates inclusion with variable array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a validator on an integer array but this array ca be modified and I think my validator inclusion array is not reload.

This is my validator before

```
validates :amount, presence: true, inclusion: {in: [25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250]}, on: :create
```

But now admins can enable of disable an amount

```
validates :amount, presence: true, inclusion: {in: ApplicationSetting.current.card_amounts }, on: :create
```

Any idea how in can 'reload' this inclusion array ?

ps: If I raise in the code the array in reload ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved with proc

```
validates :amount, presence: true, inclusion: {in: proc {ApplicationSetting.current.card_amounts} }, on: :create
```